# 2 Sidebars - one on each side of content

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I know this is a commonly answered question, but for some reason nothing I've tried has worked from the other Stackoverflow posts. I'm trying to have two sidebars on my website with one on each side of the main content.

I've tried using float right and float left. Block vs. inline-block etc... I'm not sure whether the the main contents should float or not. I'm using the latest google chrome browser.

HTML:

```
<!-- Main Page Contents -->
<div id="contents">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="link1.php"><div><p>link 1</p></div></a>
   </div>

    <div id="sidebar2">
        <a href="link2.php"><div><p>link 2</p></div></a>
    </div>

    <div id="mainContents"> 
        <div class="center-div" style="width: 700px;">
            <h1">This is some content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="center-div" style="width: 900px;">
            <h1>More content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .center-div
 {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: red;

 }



#contents {
overflow: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
position: fixed;
float: left;
width: 200;
margin: 5px;
margin-left: 15px;
padding: 5px;
top: 46px;
margin-top: 20px;

}

#sidebar2 {
position: fixed;
float: right;
width: 50px;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
top: 46px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#mainContents {
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Both the sidebars appear on the left side in the same position. The best I've gotten is the sidebar2 floats right of the sidebar and the contents float right of that.

Comment: I know this isn't the answer to your problem, but the code you posted has an unnecessary quotemark in one of the `<h1>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `flexbox` here is the working fiddle:

and also i have removed unnecessary css.

```css
 .center-div
 {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: red;

 }



#contents {
overflow: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
display:flex;
}

#sidebar {
width: 20%;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 20px;

}

#sidebar2 {
width: 20%;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#mainContents {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Page Contents -->
<div id="contents">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="link1.php"><div><p>link 1</p></div></a>
   </div>

    

    <div id="mainContents"> 
        <div class="center-div">
            <h1>This is some content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="center-div" >
            <h1>More content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar2">
        <a href="link2.php"><div><p>link 2</p></div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: there is mistakes in `html` and `css` which i have corrected:

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my sidebar problem. But for some reason though, the side bars and contents are now stuck to the right side of the webpage... Not sure why.

Comment: @Kamerov did you removed style="width: 700px;" from your html? you need to remove width from html

Comment: I did and it's still like there's a margin-left: 1000px; on all the content.

Comment: Any suggestions to do it without display: flex?

Comment: use float left or display inline-block

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost correct just remove position:fixed and give proper width considering your screen as 100%

```css
.center-div
 {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: red;

 }



#contents {
overflow: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {

float: left;
width: 15%;
margin:1%;

padding: 5px;
margin-top: 20px;

}

#sidebar2 {

float:right;
width: 15%;
margin: 1%;
padding: 5px;
top: 46px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

#mainContents {
    float: left;
    width:59%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Page Contents -->
<div id="contents">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="link1.php"><div><p>link 1</p></div></a>
   </div>
    <div id="mainContents"> 
        <div class="center-div" >
            <h1>This is some content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="center-div" >
            <h1>More content</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar2">
        <a href="link2.php"><div><p>link 2</p></div></a>
    </div>


</div>
```